# ImportError: No module named itertools

Tags: 16.04, python-2.7

I am trying to run this script:

```
 python schema2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "schema2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import itertools
ImportError: No module named itertools
```

and I am continuosly getting this error. my python version is 2.7.12...any idea why? Is my python broken? if so how can i safely fix it pls?

Comment: Maybe it is a `python-minimal`. Try install real `python` with `sudo apt-get install python`.

Comment: How did you install Python 2.7.12?

Comment: i am not sure if it came with ubuntu or i installed it with anaconda...only met this problem with this library...i tried sudo apt-get install python but no luck

Comment: actually my ubuntu is 16.04...i mistyped

Comment: Update your Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, then try install `python` again.

Comment: i tried this and sudo apt-get install python but no luck

Comment: i actually think i installed python 2.7 with anaconda

Comment: @user42967 Did `sudo apt-get install python` succeed? If yes, try running the script with the system Python binary `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: no unfortunately didn't work

Comment: @user42967 What didn't work?

Comment: when i tried to run the script i had the same error